# Different Url's on Azure add-in call

Tags: office365, openid-connect, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

can anybody explain why the first call on an Azure add-in with OpenIdConnectAuthentication from SharePoint Online has the Url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantGuid/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxx&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%...
```

and the second call has the Url

```
https://yyy.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/cloudappsredirect.aspx?addintype=FileHandler&usemds=false&appurl=https%...&params
```

Is there a possibility to get the parameters from Url2 also from the first call?

EDIT

Got a tip from a mate and from the [GPX file handler](https://github.com/OfficeDev/GPX-FileHandler/tree/master/MVCO365DemoMT/App_Start) code.

in the Notifications of the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions you can specify the RedirectToIdentityProvider Func. Here you can save all the necessary informations of the Query string in a cookie, because Session doesn't work here.

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
{
   var directoryAndFilenameReferrer = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query.Split('&').Where(x => x.StartsWith("itemurl", StringComparison.Ordinal)).FirstOrDefault();
   var directoryAndFilename = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(directoryAndFilenameReferrer).Split('/');
   context.Response.Cookies.Append("cookie_Filename", directoryAndFilename[directoryAndFilename.Length - 1]);
   return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Don't forget to delete the cookie afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: No, these are two different services that serve different purposes based on different sets of information.

This seems to be a filehandler app. Like any other app, it's "external" to the Microsoft cloud workloads (SharePoint, Exchange, etc.) Therefore it needs to provide some evidence (token) that it has been authorized to work with the desired workload (SharePoint/OneDrive in this case.)

The first call is to the one and only authorization service in the Microsoft business cloud - to verify the credentials of the app (and the user). The result of that is an authorization token. This service knows nothing about drives and files.

The second call is file-specific - your app has to discover the GET and PUT URLs of the file it will be handling. That information is only stored in SharePoint/OneDrive. That's why this call to SharePoint/OneDrive is inevitable. As I mentioned above, this call requires an authorization token that is acquired through the first call.

If your question is why SharePoint doesn't produce its own authorization tokens, that's a topic for a longer discussion. Briefly, a separate authorization service allows apps to access multiple workloads with a single user authentication and consent, and is less error prone. You can read about OAuth 2.0 here - http://oauth.net/2/.

Comment: thanks for the clarification of the authorization service. With a bit of trickiness it's possible to store filename and other url params of the first call into a cookie as I wrote in my edit above.